# Conditional formatting with cell values based on their row

Tags: excel-formula

I'm currently doing a small side project where I'm converting images into excel spreadsheets. I have a python program which turns each cell into a range between 0 and 255 (RGB color codes).

I had made this a while back and don't actually remember how I colored each row with conditional formatting.

Essentially, I need to select each row, turn it a shade of red. Then I need to select each alternate row (MOD 2 = 0) and turn each of those into a shade of green. Finally, I need to select each third row (MOD 3 = 0) and turn those into a shade of blue.

Again, to reiterate, I'm having trouble with actually selecting the rows. Is there any way I can do this (without doing it by hand)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. Highlight rows to get formatted
2. Click on "Conditional Formatting" and then "New Rule"
3. Click the last option on the upper part of the box "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Type this =MOD(ROW(),1)=0
5. Click "Format" and select a fill color (Red in this example)
6. Repeat it two more time for the other two colors
7. =MOD(ROW(),2)=0 for Green & =MOD(ROW(),3)=0 for Blue

check the below image[image]

Comment: I think you mean =mod(row(),3)=1 for red and =mod(row(),3)=2 for green?

Comment: I gave the suggested answer based on my understanding but I think you are right
=MOD(ROW(),3)=0 for red
=MOD(ROW(),3)=1 for green
=MOD(ROW(),3)=2 for blue
it looks better